# How do you create a custom attribute for MS Test?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

If you want to create a custom attribute for MS test (say [Repeat(3)]
how would you do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looking more, here is one possible place to start:
[Peli's blog](http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/IntroducingYUnitAMicroscopicUnitTestFrameworkForTeamTest.aspx)

I'm still looking for other good resources or examples.

Comment: It looks like this link is no longer valid.  Did you find any other resources?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will like the answer: there is no supported way. However, there is a codeplex project [MSTestExtensions](http://www.codeplex.com/MSTestExtensions) implementing a work around and a [blog post](http://callumhibbert.blogspot.com/2008/01/extending-mstest.html) about how MSTestExtensions works. (Using ContextBoundObject)

Comment: I don't think that is correct, since MS has documentation that allows such extensibility (though it sucks..)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165914(VS.80).aspx

Roy

Answer (score 0):

Roy, If you are using Typemock Isolator, you can use the AOP Decorator to extend any test framework.

Comment: I'm looking for built in extensibility mechanism, not an external work around. thanks :)